# Linux commands to fetch all files,size and path of files from all directories and subdirectories

Tags: php, linux

Can anyone please guide me, how do I use Linux commands in  PHP code to fetch  all files names and their size and path of files from all directories and subdirectories.

I am running a scan code. where I need to fetch the files and perform a scan. The issue is that when I run on linux server it takes too long to perform the scan. So, i thought of adding linux commands to my php script and check that if server is linux then instead of my function, those coomands can be used and hence increase increase the speed of scan.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in PHP rather than any scripting language with which you are more familiar?

Comment: You start by looking at http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Comment: Surely you do not need **all** of the files:  What do you expect to find in `/dev/null`? Why look in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`? It might take a while to read all of `/dev/sda1` ? Are you **certain** you should scan these? Who knows you might eventually pull out of `/dev/random`? If you only need the files in the webserver directory, that is a start for narrowing down the scan.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive ls will work:

```
<?php
exec('ls -lR', $output);
```

Comment: `exec()` only returns the last line of the output.

Comment: fail on my part.. edit made

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = shell_exec("find dirname -ls");
```